# How do I edit the search text in vim?

Tags: search, vim, text, edit

I've searched online for this a while, but I couldn't find an answer.

What I want to do is to edit the previously entered search text in vim.

For example, say I just searched for "FooClass". Then I want to search for "FooMethod", but rather than typing the whole word from scratch, I would like to backspace 5 times to remove "Class", and just type "Method" after "Foo".

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Press <kbd>/</kbd> then <kbd>Up</kbd>, then backspace five times.  (Probably assumes `nocp` is set).

---

Stop reading now unless you want to learn some fancy new tricks...

If you want to get clever, you can also use `Ctrl-R` to pull things onto the search box (e.g. put the cursor on a word, press <kbd>/</kbd>, then press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>W</kbd> and it will pull the word under the cursor onto the search line: similar to pressing <kbd>*</kbd>, but editable and without the word boundaries).

If you want to get **really** clever, you can use all of vimscript's cleverness to set `@/` to be whatever you want to search for and then press <kbd>n</kbd>:

```
:let @/ = 'Foo' . 'Method'
n
```

Probably more than you wanted to know though...

See:

```
:help 'nocp'
:help c_CTRL-R
:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W
:help *
:help quote/
:help :let-@
```

Comment: Al -- Thanks, some nice little tidbits in there. . .

Comment: The ctrl+r trick sounds cool but for some reason I get /<80>kb^[ rather than the word under the cursor. Any idea what might cause that?

Comment: Probably because it's Ctrl+R , Ctrl+W   instead of Ctrl+R , W .  This is well documented in :help c_Ctrl-R

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't very clear on that.  I should have said "hold ctrl and press r then w".  I'll edit the answer to make it clearer.  For information, Ctrl-R then release Ctrl and press W pulls the contents of the 'w' register onto the command line (into which you can put stuff with e.g. "wyy).

Answer (score 10):

I find editing the history is best for complicated searches. You can edit the search history with `q/`. Just edit the line you want to use and press enter to execute the line.

There is also a [great vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/) on refining search patterns using this technique.

```
:h q/
```

Comment: Thanks. I use `q:` every so often.  Somehow I didn't realize same concept extended to searches.